# add superscript to `\matrix (m) [table]` brace in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-matrix

I would like to add a superscript to an existing brace in a `\matrix (m) [table]`. This will denote the transpose. I need to decorate the brace to preserve spacing with another `\matrix (m) [table]`.

My matrix and attempt is given by

```
\documentclass{article}
%%% tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,decorations.pathreplacing,matrix,calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calligraphy}% AFTER decorations.text
\tikzset{ 
    table/.style={
        matrix of math nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={rectangle,text width=3em,align=center},
        text depth=1.25ex,
        text height=2.5ex,
        nodes in empty cells,
        left delimiter=[,
        right delimiter={]},
        ampersand replacement=\&
    }
}
\newcommand*{\connectorH}[4][]{
  \draw[#1] (#3) -| ($(#3) !#2! (#4)$) |- (#4);% https://hugoideler.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/connector.tex
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,decoration=brace]
    \matrix (m) [table] {
      %1     %2     %3     %4       %5    %6        %7
      A_{1,:}^\top\\
      A_{2,:}^\top\\
    };
    \node at (m-1-1.north east) {$\qquad\quad{\top}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

but the transpose only ends up in the middle of the matrix, not decorating the righthand brace of the matrix. Is there a good way to do this while still using `\matrix (m) [table]`?

Comment: Maybe you want to use `\node` and to add an `at`: `\node at (m-1-1) {$\red{\top}$};`?

Comment: @JasperHabicht: ah, this gets it: `\node at (m-1-1.north east) {$\qquad\quad\red{\top}$};` but it feels like there might be a btter way?

Comment: I can't reproduce the complete picture, because you did not provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). I don't know where the brace is, for example, because I don't know the defintion for  `table`. Please add this information to your code snippet above.

Comment: You could try `\node[anchor=west, xshift=0.67em] at (m-1-1.north east) {$\top$};`.

Comment: thanks, will use that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like `\node[anchor=west, xshift=0.67em] at (m-1-1.north east) {$\top$};`, but you could actually also just replace the right delimiter (which would also render the superscript in the correct font size):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{ 
    table/.style={
        matrix of math nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            text width=3em,
            align=center
        },
        text depth=1.25ex,
        text height=2.5ex,
        nodes in empty cells,
        left delimiter={[},
        right delimiter={]},
        ampersand replacement=\&
    }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [table, right delimiter={]^{\top}}] {
      A_{1,:}^{\top} \\
      A_{2,:}^{\top} \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]